# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord data flow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, relational-database, join

I'm currently trying to build an application that works similar to something like [Trello](https://trello.com/). I have `users` that can create `boards`. Each user can have a different `role` depending on what board they are on. Because I'm fairly new to Rails, I just want to make sure that I'm following the "Rails way" and best practices. Here is my schema:

```
create_table "boards", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "user_boards", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "board_id"
    t.integer "role"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "lists", "boards"
```

As you can see, I added the `role` attribute to the `UserBoard` join table. A `User has_many Boards` & `Board has_many Users` both `through: UserBoard`. Depending on the `User` & `Board` they can have a different `role`.

user_board.rb

```
class UserBoard < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :board
  enum role: { admin: 0, member: 1 }
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_boards
  has_many :boards, through: :user_boards
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

board.rb

```
class Board < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_boards
  has_many :users, through: :user_boards
  has_many :lists, dependent: :destroy
  include AssociateUsersToBoards

  def self.assign_board_to_user(user, board)
    AssociateUsersToBoards.build_association(user, board)
  end
end
```

I'm just trying to figure if this is the best way to handle this & if there is a better way to set it up so that my queries & updates can be a bit cleaner. Right now when a `User` creates a `Board` you can see that I'm using the `ActiveRecord:create` function. The reason as to why I'm using `create` is because when I try to use `new` or `build` the association in the join table doesn't get made. That seems wrong to me that I would not be able to perform `current_user.boards.new(board_params)` or `current_user.boards.build(board_params)`:

```
def create
  @board = current_user.boards.new(board_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if current_user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @board, notice: 'Board was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @board }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @board.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

But I also want to set the `role` to `admin`.. The only way I can think of doing this is `current_user.user_boards.find_by(board_id:@board).update_attribute(:role, 'admin')` after I have saved my record in my `board#create` action. This query kinda makes me want to vomit & I cannot believe that there isn't a better approach.

My `board_params` are very simple & just allow the basic title:

```
def board_params
  params.require(:board).permit(:title)
end
```

---

### EDIT

---

I also wanted to add the form I'm using to submit the `board` to make sure there isn't something wrong within that:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <%= form_with(model: board, local: true) do |form| %>
    <% if board.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(board.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this board from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
          <% board.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= form.label :title %><br/>
      <%= form.text_field :title, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= form.submit 'Create Board', class: 'btn btn-small btn-success btn-block' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

All suggestions, tips and constructive criticism is very much appreciated as I try to learn/familiarize myself more & more w/ the Ruby language & Rails framework.

Answer (score 3):

You don't show `board_params`, but perhaps it should look something like:

```
def board_params
  params.require(:board).permit(:something, :whatever_else).merge!(role: :admin)
end
```

Then, do something like:

```
def create
  @board = current_user.boards.new(board_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @board.save
      format.html { redirect_to @board, notice: 'Board was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @board }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @board.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

That ought to create a new board with the `user_id` and `role` set correctly.

BTW, I personally prefer:

```
class UserBoard < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :board
  enum role: {
    admin:  0,
    member: 1
  }
end
```

So I don't have to worry about `enum` position in the arrays as discussed in the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

> Note that when an array is used, the implicit mapping from the values to database integers is derived from the order the values appear in the array. In the example, :active is mapped to 0 as it's the first element, and :archived is mapped to 1. In general, the i-th element is mapped to i-1 in the database.
>
> Therefore, once a value is added to the enum array, its position in the array must be maintained, and new values should only be added to the end of the array. To remove unused values, the explicit hash syntax should be used.

Comment: My `board_params` is running: `params.require(:board).permit(:title).merge!(role: :admin)`. The problem is that it is returning: `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'role' for Board.)`. I suspect this is because `role` belongs to the `user_boards` table & not the `board` table. Another problem I'm running into is that `current_user.boards.new(board_params)` is not creating an association to the users boards...

Comment: So it turns out that if I'm going to create the association of a board to a user by doing `@board = current_user.boards.new(board_params)`, I have to be saving the `current_user` & not `@board.save` which is peculiar & I do not fully understand why. I'm starting to think maybe my associations aren't correct? Although it appears that I'm following all the examples out there.

Answer (score 0):

So I did find quite a simple & what seems to be an elegant way of handling the auto completion of a users `role` when they create a board. Here is my solution:

```
class UserBoard < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :board
  enum role: { admin: 0, member: 1 }
  before_create :set_admin

  private

  def set_admin
    self.role = 'admin'
  end
end
```

I've simply added a `before_create` callback method that will set the role on the join table record to `admin` before every record created. It can then be adjusted appropriately later on.

I did & still may have some confusion surrounding my `board#create` method. I have done some research & think I can explain why @jvillian solution for creating the `user board` association wouldn't work. So this was the provided method for creating the association:

```
  @board = current_user.boards.new(board_params)
    if @board.save
```

However, what would occur here is that a `Board` record would get created, you could even see how it was 'associated' to the user when you ran `current_user.boards`. But a record in the join table wouldn't be created. I read that in the case of a has_many association, **the child is saved on saving the parent** if child.new_record? returns true (child was not yet saved to db), or the foreign_key column needs to be updated. Thus:

1. Adding object to association on saved parent (`current_user.save`) does save the new child.
2. Adding object to association on unsaved parent (`@board.save`) doesn't save the foreign key value (no join table record created)
3. If unsaved parent is being saved & has some child objects in association cache, those objects are saved to update foreign_key.

So in this instance `current_user` (User object) is the parent & has an association of `@board` cached, which then updates the foreign_key & creates the join table record. On the other hand, saving `@board` will save a new `Board` object & update the cached `Board` object assigned to `current_user.boards` but DOESN'T create a foreign_key.

I hope this makes sense & even more importantly is right. Please let me know otherwise. I want to make sure that I have a correct understanding.